# Plotting a frequency line graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to learn to plot with matplotlib however I can't seem to make a line graph where the
x - axis is the value from a text file and the y - axis is the frequency of the value in the file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
thingTxt = open("thing.txt", "r")


for line in open('thing.txt', 'r'):
    lines = [i for i in line.split()]
    x.append(lines[0])
    y.append() #Dont know what to put here


plt.table = "test"
plt.xlabel = "date"
plt.ylabel = "Frequency Count"
plt.yticks()
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', c = 'g')

plt.show()
```

and for example if the .txt file were to have the values (each value on a different line)

01
04
06
03
04
05

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to draw a line, then you will need to update your code as below. This will draw one line based on the values in the text file as x-coordinates. For Y, I am using an incrementing number range from 0 to length of x. This is probably one of the simplest graphs. Note that all info in csv/txt will be considered as string, so need to convert it to int. Usually you would keep the incrementing value (or date) in X-axis so that you can see the changes of Y to the X-axis. But, left it as is based on what you had written.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
thingTxt = open("thing.txt", "r")

for line in open('thing.txt', 'r'):
    x = [int(i) for i in line.split()] #Read line into a list having converted the text to int
    
y = range(len(x)) #A list of integers from 0 to length of x

#plt.table = "test"  #Commented as we are not using this
plt.xlabel = "date"
plt.ylabel = "Frequency Count"
plt.yticks()
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', c = 'g')

plt.show()
```

[image]